# Pass all arguments after delimiter to another command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to pass on *all* arguments from a shell script to another command *unless* one of the arguments is a `--`, in which case I want to use the arguments before the `--` in my script and only pass on the arguments after the `--`.

For example, if my script is `foo.sh`:

```
./foo.sh -a bar -p qux -- --recursive -p 8080
```

I would like to use the `-a` and first `-p` arguments in my script, and pass on the `--recursive` and second `-p`.

My initial idea is to first iterate over each argument until a `--` is found, then use `shift` to extract the arguments I want, then pass the rest to the other command with `$@`, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way to do this.

As a side note, I am currently using `getopts` to extract arguments, so a solution that works with that would be optimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want, simplified example taken from the [GNU manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/getopts.html#tag_04_62_17).

```
#!/bin/bash 
aflag=
bflag=
cflag=
dflag=
while getopts abcd name
do
  case $name in
    a)    aflag=1;;
    b)    bflag=1;;
    c)    cflag=1;;
    d)    dflag=1;;
  esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
printf "Remaining arguments are: %s\n" "$*"
```

Result

```
$ ./test.sh  -a -b -- -c -d
Remaining arguments are: -c -d
```

---

Relevant parts of the manual for completness

> Each time it is invoked, the getopts utility shall place the value of the next option in the shell variable specified by the name operand and the index of the next argument to be  processed  in  the shell variable OPTIND . Whenever the shell is invoked, OPTIND shall be initialized to 1.
>
> [...]
>
> When the end of options is encountered, the getopts utility shall exit with a return value greater than zero; the shell variable OPTIND shall be set to the index of the first non-option-argument, where the first "--" argument is considered to be an option-argument if there are no other non-option-arguments appearing before it, or the value "$#" +1 if there are no non-option-arguments; the name variable shall be set to the question-mark character. Any of the following shall identify the end of options: the special option "--", finding an argument that does not begin with a '-', or encountering an error.

Comment: Perfect, this works almost exactly as I wanted. It just doesn't work properly if no `--` is passed, but I fixed it by only running the `getopts` loop if a `--` exists in the argument list. Thanks!